# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException

Tags: java, lucene, sparql, jena

Still in the same project, i get a problem when i try to run text search with Jena and using SPARQL. The error description says:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "." ". "" at line 2, column 53.
```

I think the problem comes from the query. The query code shows below:

```
public static void queryData(Dataset dataset){
    String prefix = "PREFIX email: <" + App.URI_PREFIX+">" +
            "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>";

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'good'");
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE " +
            "{ ?s text:query (email:content 'good'." +
            " ?s email:content ?text . " +
            " }" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    }finally { dataset.end();}
    long finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    double time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println ("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms", time));

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'bad'");
    query = "SELECT * WHERE" +
            "{ (?s ?score ?lit) text:query (email:content 'bad' \"highlight:s:<em class='hiLite'> | e:</em>\") ." +
            " ?s email:content ?text . " +
            " }" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);

    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    } finally { dataset.end() ; }
    finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms",  time));
}`
```

does it need a change in query code especially in SPARQL? please advise me. thank you

Comment: I mean, why don't you print the query? The error is obvious ... in the first query a closing bracket `)` before the dot `.` - always count the number of open vs closed brackets ... would have been faster than opening a question here

Comment: @AKSW i get it now. sorry if i am not careful enough. i put my question here because i need another person to look for where is my fault. thank you so much!